# What is the initial velocity when dealing with projectile motion?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, physics, projectile-motion

my question is with the image below what would the initial velocity be?
My teacher says the initial velocity is 40 m/s however my textbook says the initial velocity is 20$ \sqrt{3} $ **i** + 20 **j** m/s.
So who is right my teacher or my textbook?

[image]

Comment: Book says $\sqrt{3} i + 20 j$ or $20 \sqrt{3} i + 20 j$? If latter, the book is correct. Your teacher is not wrong either but referring to velocity, one should state direction too. For example, in this case it is 40 m/s at angle $30^0$ to the horizontal.

Comment: @MathLover Your correct I forget to write the '20'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Velocity is usually a vector, and speed a scalar (the modulus of the velocity). So if you are picky on the terms, only the book is right.

Comment: This is the better answer in my opinion. Uncluttered by irrelevancies. The only thing that would've made it perfect, in my opinion, is to explicitly state that velocity (being a vector) has a magnitude (also called speed) *and* a direction.